# Height Auto and Height 100%

Tags: html, css

I see a lot of people doing this with their css:

```
height:auto !important;
height: 100%;
```

What is this actually accomplishing (what's the point)? Furthermore, won't the `!important` always override the other attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because [IE6 will ignore the first `height` declaration](http://haslayout.net/css/IE6--important-Ignore-Bug). [This thread](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3128123.htm) explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing that springs to mind is that IE6 ignores !important when it's not the last rule in the selector, which makes the next line a fallback for IE6.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it's because IE6, but what are the odds http://www.ie6countdown.com and more !important where are they.